# polymorphisim java

Tags: java

I'm getting the fine after computing the method  `computeFine()` it returns the result `0`  each time I put any `period`

Please check it here because it is very long and it's hard to past it in SOF

http://paste.org/pastebin/view/40017

Comment: You realize you're printing out the fine for the same object six times, right?

Comment: Please reduce your code to the *minimum* required to demonstrate the problem, and then post it here (see http://sscce.org/).

Comment: Loops, man, loops. And as Mat said, only one item there falls below the maximum load period,and it's not the one you print over and over. Another reason to use loops.

Comment: At least part of your problem is that you're comparing strings using `==` instead of `.equals()`

Answer (score 2):

Your method is not too long. Here it is:

```
public  double computeFine( int loanPeriod){
  double loanPeriodFine= 0.0;
  if (loanPeriod <= maximumLoanPeriod)
  {
   loanPeriodFine= 0.0;
  }else if (loanPeriod > maximumLoanPeriod){
   if (getSubject()=="cs")
   {
    loanPeriodFine= loanPeriod-maximumLoanPeriod*10.0;
   }else{
    loanPeriodFine =  loanPeriod-maximumLoanPeriod*5.0;
   }
  }
```

You can get 0 here if

1. `loanPeriod <= maximumLoanPeriod`
2. `maximumLoanPeriod` is 0

As I can see from your code the loadPeriod passed to this method is always 7 while the maximalLoanPeriod for most items is greater. So in almost all cases fine should be 0. The only exception is book "Java Programming 3v".

Answer (score 0):

Just one suggestion:

The following -

```
if(getYear() < 2000) {   
    loanPeriodFine = loanPeriodFine * (20/100);   
} else if(getYear() > 2000) {   
    loanPeriodFine = loanPeriodFine * (20/100);
}
```

can be reduced to -

```
if(getYear() != 2000) {
    loanPeriodFine = loanPeriodFine * (20/100);
}
```